# Is there a reason for this naming convention on static final variables?

Tags: java, oop, static, naming-conventions, final

I'm studying from the HeadFirst Java book and currently on the Numbers and statics chapter. They recently introduced the concept of static final variables. Perfectly clear the way they were explained. My question is, they have named the variable using the class name + some arbitrary name, separated by underscore, all in caps. Here's an example.

```
    public class Foo {
        public static final int FOO_SUM = 5;
    }
```

Why is this?

Comment: My guess is that it's a convention for naming constants which was borrowed from earlier languages. For example, in C, it is normal to write `#define FOO_SUM 5` to define a constant (not as an immutable variable, but as a macro for the pre-processor). The use of all-uppercase names in C was useful to distinguish pre-processor code from other code.

Comment: It is a convention. The format is known as [UPPER_SNAKE_CASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). It should only be used on `static final` primitives or immutables only. It signals something that would be regarded as constant.

Comment: Including the class name is not part of the convention; I guess it was just done that way in the book because it's an arbitrary example and "FOO" is an arbitrary word.

Comment: The class name is used to identify the variable. Imagine you have a `class A` with a `public static final int NUMBER = 1;` and a class `B` with `public static final int NUMBER = 2;`. To reference `A`'s `NUMBER`, one writes `A.NUMBER`. To reference `B`'s number, one writes `B.NUMBER`.

Comment: @kaya3 That clears it up. I guess it was just a way of emphasizing that it belong to class ```Foo``` :)

Comment: @Turing85 Alright, so it can be named just anything as long as it is in upper snake case, no need for class name up front when declaring?

Comment: I'd say it's better to *not* put the class name in the constant name, because you already use the class name to access it; `Foo.FOO_SUM` is redundant since it has the class name twice.

Comment: Since it is already embedded within the `Foo` class, I would specifically *avoid* the redundancy of having Foo in the constant name.

Comment: That solves my doubts @kaya3 Perhaps it was a way for the book to emphasize to which class that constant belonged

Answer (score 1):

It is a convention. The format is known as [SNAKE_CASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). It should be used on `static final` primitives or [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) only. This is defined, amongst other things, in the [official Oracle style guide](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html) and the [Google Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2-specific-identifier-names) It signals something that would be regarded as constant. One should **not** use the SNAKE_CASE for `static final` fields, if the objects are mutable.

The inclusion of the class name is for the calling side. Imagine you have two classes `A` and `B`, both having a `public static final int NUMBER` variable:

```
public class A {
    public static final int NUMBER = 1;
}

public class B {
    public static final int NUMBER = 2;
}

public class Ideone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(A.NUMBER); // = 1
        System.out.println(B.NUMBER); // = 2
    }
}
```

Within the same class, one can forego the class name, e.g.:

```
public class A {
    public static final int NUMBER = 1;

    public int getNumberPlusTwo() {
        return NUMBER + 2; // returns 3
    }
}
```

If one would want to reference `B`'s `NUMBER` in `A`, then the class name must be used again:

```
public class A {
    ...
    public int getBsNumberPlusTwo() {
        return B.NUMBER + 2; // returns 4
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8c66kV)